# SVN connection refused

Tags: linux, svn

I'm having trouble checking out a project via svn.  I have a repository set up at svn://consideropen.com/home/consider/rvsubversion/project/trunk.

I have no problem checking out the project in NetBeans, but, when I ssh to another server (not the same server as the repository) and run

```
svn checkout svn://example.com/home/consider/rvsubversion/project/trunk
```

I get a connection refused error.

Why is this happening?

Comment: @Strelok: [Don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question/46037#46037) [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222)

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24480421/1413643

Comment: @Strelok: This absolutely is programming related. In fact it couldn't be any more programming related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly your server is behind a firewall that only permits certain ports through such as 22, 80, and 8080 for example.  It might not permit the standard svn protocol port 3690 to pass through.

Try `telnet consideropen.com 3690` and see if you get:

> ( success ( 1 2 ( ANONYMOUS ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries ) )

If you don't then you are blocked.  Your other option would be to set up the repository using subversion with WebDAV.  Then your server would be able to access it over port 80 which is usually open.

Comment: Also, you can try that with netcat: `nc consideropen.com 3690`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to master [nmap](http://nmap.org) - very powerful port scanning tool

In your case it will be:

> $ nmap -sT -r -n -vv -p80,8080 example.com

where `-sT` mean direct TCP connection, `-sS` - SYNC or silience

`-vv` - very verbose

`-r` - don't randomize ports

`-n` - don't make DNS resolve

`-p{xxx}` - ports to scan, different masks are supported, e.g. `80,8081-8088,8090`

optional `-P0` means don't ping a target host

Comment: example.com might require DNS resolving.

Comment: @eaykin: Sure. Usually I use nmap against intranet IPs so wrote this argument out of habit